# How to remove Blinking text box on List View

Tags: listview, vb6, textbox

A blinking textbox appears every time I make a selection on the list view. 
I can type on it and only disappears when I press Enter key. I have no text box behind it. 
How can I remove it? Thanks

Here's what it looks like - >

[image]

Here’s the property of my list view - >

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Mark for adding the photos. I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change labelEdit  to Manual. It text box correspond to element 0.

i dont remember the order but it is set when you add item

set lvw = Lvw.addItem(,[Text of element 0],,)

Comment: Hi Carlos. That seemed to solve that problem. But what is labeledit for? I have other list views that have automatic label edit but the blinking textbox does not appear. Thanks :)

Comment: It's for editing the text in column 1. It only appears when clicking an already highlighted item.